# How to work with SVG dowloaded from web in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Apple introduced SVG support in Xcode 12. Is it possible natively to work with SVG downloaded from the web? I need to download SVG from a server and display it on the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Natively, no. The Xcode 12 improvement is only for an svg that you put in an asset catalog beforehand. iOS has no support for displaying a downloaded svg. You could look for a third party library, however.